# Vim and Tmux rendering error

Tags: vim, rendering, tmux, nerdtree, irssi

I have a problem when using Tmux and Vim. As you can see on the picture when I use nerdtree (or irssi, actually any terminal app), I have these kind of rendering problems.

Every key I type modify the entire terminal rendering.

It's only a graphical bug, but it prevents me from working properly. For example, on the screenshot I submitted, nerdtree is opened.

The rendering issue comes mostly when the lines are too long (wrapping) or when I have to scroll (down or up).

[image]

I haven't found a way to solve it. Does anybody has this problem too? I really don't know how to solve this.

Many thanks!

Comment: haha thanks Kent ;) thank you for adding me the pic too :)

Comment: u r welcome.. I am sitting in office, tinypic was backlisted by our company proxy for some reason. Therefore I cannot see your image until I let SO bring it here.... :) you better briefly explain, what problem do you have. The screenshot cannot be enlarged, one (at least me) can hardly see the problem there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim goes whack with tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374503/vim-goes-whack-with-tmux)

Answer (score 7):

Solution already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18056690/2987828):

```
tmux set-option -g utf8 off
:set tenc=latin1
```

or

```
tmux set-option -g utf8 on
:set tenc=utf8
```

depending on your terminal configuration.

If this didn't fix anything, try

```
:set isprint=
```

which will at least let you work, short of seeing magical graphic characters.

Comment: Indeed that was the solution! Thank you very much :)

Comment: The usual way on stackoverflow.com to say that is to click on the accept mark just below the score (currently the big 0) of my answer.

Comment: I know, and I have tried but I need 15 reputations to be able to upvote, but don't worry I will  come back to it and will not forget to upvote it. It saved me lots of time!

Comment: @Jim: You talk about "upvoting", I talk about "Accept". The "Accept" button will also reward you some rep.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a colour issue? If so these might help you:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux
- http://reyhan.org/2013/12/colours-on-vim-and-tmux.html
- [Vim: Difference between t_Co=256 and term=xterm-256color in conjunction with TMUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375992/vim-difference-between-t-co-256-and-term-xterm-256color-in-conjunction-with-tmu)

Answer (score 0):

`export TERM=screen-256color` solved my issue. See more in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245919/vim-nerdtree-corrupts-when-using-tmux).