# Vim NerdTree corrupts when using Tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, nerdtree

As described in the title, the nerdtree just corrupts when I'm scrolling down the screen in vim by "control + f". As shown in
[image: screen shot], most of the folder information, supposed to appear in the left bar, is tangled and covered by the file content.

I did find similar issues posted in stackoverflow, but none of those got a good solution yet.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an issue with your `TERM` environment variable. Please ensure you've `export TERM=screen-256color`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the setting of the `TERM`. It indeed solves my problem.

Comment: My issue got solved after setting 'export TERM=screen-256color' in my bashrc.

Here's a few doc/link to complement/explain his solution: 
 
1. [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) noted "most display problems are due to incorrect TERM setting"
2. [another question relates to 'TERM'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139082/zsh-set-term-screen-256color-in-tmux-but-xterm-256color-without-tmux)

Comment: Ah, great that my hunch was right! I've added a full answer. Please accept it by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

As you've found out from the [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ), "most display problems are due to incorrect TERM setting"